# Service in Android

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I started to use the ROS recently.
I'm trying to call a Service in Android.
The Service is running on rospy.
Right now I have the server working well.
The client (Android) has been implemented using two different modes:

- public class Client extends AbstractNodeMain: generates an exception that I do not understand why.
- public class Client implements NodeMain: there is no exception, but it also does not communicate with the server.

Someone can help me?
Hope for help! Thanks..
Paulo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55922/service-in-android/) by [paulofinseca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4259/paulofinseca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Paulo

The following code worked for me in implementing a ServiceClient in Android. Note that HMMv2/get_Joint_State.srv is a custom service of mine.

In the OnStart(ConnectedNode node) method (but before you implement a cancellable loop:

```
final ServiceClient<HMMv2.get_Joint_StateRequest, HMMv2.get_Joint_StateResponse> client;
          
          
            try 
            {
                client = node.newServiceClient("HMMv2Cont/JointState", HMMv2.get_Joint_State._TYPE);
            
            } 
            catch (ServiceNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
            }
        
            final HMMv2.get_Joint_StateRequest request=client.newMessage();
              
            request.setJointName("joints");
```

Then in the Cancellable loop, loop() function the code to call the service is:

```
client.call(request, new ServiceResponseListener<HMMv2.get_Joint_StateResponse>()    {

                                @Override
                            public void onFailure(RemoteException arg0) 
                            {
                                Log.d("Jointrequest Client", "failed to call service");
                                throw new RosRuntimeException(arg0);
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(HMMv2.get_Joint_StateResponse message) 
                            {
                                                           //do something with the response
                                hPos.set(0, 0, (message.getJointState().getPosition()[0]-512)*Math.PI/512);             
                            


                            }

                                });
```

hope this example helps you. I think the main issue I found in implementing this was the declaration of a final ServiceClient types. But I've used this format a couple of times and it works.

cheers
Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulofinseca](https://answers.ros.org/users/4259/paulofinseca/) on 2013-02-23**:
I have something similar. But when I run, an error occurs:

02-23 17:07:52.778: E/AndroidRuntime(671): org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception: paulofonseca-PC:37008
02-23 17:07:52.778: E/AndroidRuntime(671):  at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:109

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-02-24**:
check your logcat and see where in your program the exception is thrown. The reference you give only specifies a library file (TcpClient.java) but if you can scroll down you should see your file name with a line number. This should give some clue as to what is causing this exception.

**Comment by [thomasL](https://answers.ros.org/users/16906/thomasl/) on 2014-05-22**:
I have the same issue :
org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception: ubuntu:38403
at org.ros.internal.transport.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:109)
Have you find a solution?